# Выполнить запрос в третью таблицу

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
select (тут условие) from
```

Как в данном случаи выставить условие в наименованиях полей. Если текущее поле не является пустым, выполняем еще один запрос третью таблицу и записываем результат в отдельное поле на выходе.

Если поле не пустое, к примеру содержит `1,2,3,4`, необходимо выполнить запрос в третью таблицу и вытащить все записи с данными id. Так чтобы виртуальная переменная содержала массив из тех строчек, что нашли в третьей таблице.

Comment: Гм-м-м... Нужны два JOIN?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.